# How to display the current device's IMEI in a TextView?

Tags: android

I tried to display the Device's IMEI in textView using this code, but it doesn't work. Nothing appears when I run the program.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    getDeviceIMEI();
            }
        });     

private void getDeviceIMEI() {
      TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      String IMEI_Number_Holder = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
      textView.setText(IMEI_Number_Holder);
    }
```

I also added this permission in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this code.

```
/**
 * Return the IMEI.
 * Must hold {@code <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />}
 * @return the IMEI
 */
@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
@RequiresPermission(READ_PHONE_STATE)
public static String getIMEI() {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) Toolkit.getApp().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) return tm.getImei();
    return tm.getDeviceId();
}
```